# How to disable ant design time picker paste time

Tags: reactjs, antd

Im using **[ant design time picker](https://3x.ant.design/components/time-picker/)** for my react application, i have some conflict on the time pricker, i want to know how to disable past time before the  today current time.

This is my code

```
   getDisabledTime = () => {

        var hours = [];
        for(var i =0; i < moment().hour(); i++){
            hours.push(i);
        }
        return hours;

    }
```

```
 <TimePicker onChange={onChange} disabledTimes={this.getDisabledTimes()}/>
```

Comment: Looks like you're using the wrong prop? There is a `disabledHours`, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @maazadeeb can you please explain ?

Comment: There is no prop called `disabledTimes` on `TimePicker`, on the doc page you've linked.

Comment: @maazadeeb Hello there, i tried but not working , can you please update the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prop name is `disabledHours` and it is a function.

```
function getDisabledHours() {
  var hours = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < moment().hour(); i++) {
    hours.push(i);
  }
  return hours;
}


<TimePicker disabledHours={getDisabledHours} />
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-mccarthy-vdyh4).

Comment: Thanks for your time and solution